# Parse logical location with segments

Tags: binary, ip-address

I'm programming a c# dll to parse messages from a NX 584 Module.

I'm new to binary messages and I'm stuck with the following message:

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding the location part.
The logical location is 12 bits long, but an IP address is 4 bytes long. So I don't get how the fit an IP address in 12 bits.

What should I do with the segment size and offset? 
Also, what is meant with number of segments?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I know absolutely nothing about NX 584, but skimming through the documentation suggested that "logical location" isn't an IP address, but some kind of storage/RAM address.

12 bits would therefore seem to be the address bus size of this thing.